# How can I move apps to SD on my Samsung Galaxy Ace?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, app2sd

I want to move some apps to my SD card, and from Googling around I found that it's possible to do this if the device is rooted.  How can I root my Samsung Galaxy Ace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung Galaxy Ace runs at least Android version 2.2 and is upgradable to Gingerbread, so the device already has the possibility to move apps to the SD card. Though, not all apps support this. You can move an app to the SD card by navigating to *Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications* and click on the app you want to move. Then you click the button *Move to SD card*.

If you root your device you can move apps that doesn't support *App 2 SD*, as well (except for launchers and widgets which must be installed on internal storage). If you are running Android 2.2 you can use the desktop program [Super One Click](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) to root. If you are running 2.3 you can read a tutorial [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1282011).

Hope that helps!

Comment: @ajgam "so the device already has the possibility to move apps".  Well, know, it doesn't. It appears to put some proxy between the SD card and the file system. One "App 2 SD" program reports "the device does not have a real primary external storage or the primary external storage is emulated" (this on an SD card that contains all my music, and the music can be played on the phone).