# No root permission after installation of ClockworkModRecovery kernel

Tags: rooting, cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-ace

My smartphone is the Samsung Galaxy Ace 5380 running Android 2.3.6 and I want to flush it with the CyanogenMod 7.2

I'm performing the steps from this guide: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace:_Full_Update_Guide

I have done the "Installing the **ClockworkMod** Recovery" steps and performed a backup of my current ROM. Now I want to run a backup with **Titanium** but it says that I have no root permissions.

I thought the ClockworkMod Recovery kernel brings the root permission, because it sounds so by the guide mentioned above.

*Is there any other thing I have to do now to activate the root permission or must I root my phone additionally with some other guide*? If so, I read that after the root-procedure I have to "wipe data factory reset" and that would delete the things I want to update, but for the update itself, I need root permissions.

Comment: The root permission exists **inside** the recovery, but not in the normal system, you need to root it in there,  TL;DR - there's two partitions `recovery` and `system`, you booted into the CWM residing on recovery which is rooted, but not system.

Comment: ah that makes sense. I just read that the CyanogenMod brings the root-permission at runtime (system) with the installation of the CyanogenMod. So rooting the phone means always flash everything, and I could only save the apps, that I installed AFTER the rooting right?

Comment: not necessarily *always flash everything*, see this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18489/how-can-i-root-my-samsung-galaxy-ace

Comment: thx! that helped me :) Now I'm running CyanogenMod on my device.

Comment: @t0mm13b maybe you sum up your comments and make them an answer? They are worth at least a +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root permission exists inside the `recovery`, but not in the normal `system`, you need to root it in there.

There is usually, two partitions `recovery` and `system`, as the OP indicated, was booted into the CWM Recovery which resides on `recovery` hence is rooted, but not the normal Android system.

Comment: interesting, could you please explain how to enter CWM in recovery mode? I've installed CWM with heimdall, boot in recovery mode and install superuser on my device from the cwm interface. but when I boot the phone, I'm not root.